# Qt 5.2 with qml-box2d

Tags: box2d, qml, qt-quick, qt5.2

I'm trying to use the qml-box2d plugin in my qtquick project.
I already compiled the plugin with qt5.2, it generates two files, Box2Dd.dll and libBox2Dd.a.
The problem is when I try to use it, because when I compiled my project I found this error:

```
module "Box2D" is not installed
import Box2D 1.0
```

how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Where are your .dll file located ?

Comment: my file.dll is where the Qt complier created it